# Bold pzc for mathmode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, bold, bm

Is there a decent way of bolding the pzc font defined as

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

in the math mode. Giving \bm a try as below did not reveal anything

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\begin{document}
$\mathpzc{A}$ is a set and $\bm{ \mathpzc{B}}$ is a polyset.
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Boldface Zapf Chancery is not available.

Comment: Boldface Zapf Chancery is available as a separate font for use with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, see for example https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-zapf-chancery. The bold version is not very similar to the italic though, it is much less 'curly'.

Comment: For my humble opinion you use the best answer of @egreg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Zapf Chancery font (or clone thereof), is not available in boldface.

If you're willing to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can exploit TeX Gyre Chorus, which is a clone of Zapf Chancery and boldface can be faked.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\chorus}{TeX Gyre Chorus}[
  NFSSFamily=chorus,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathzc}{TU}{chorus}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathzcb}{TU}{chorus}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathzc{A}\ne\mathzcb{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I was editing my answer, but you remain my admiration and esteem. It is a wonderful fake.

Answer (score 7):

According totally with the user @egreg there are two extreme options:

1. or using `contour`package (for my humble opinion it is a good compromise):

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{contour}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\begin{document}
$\mathpzc{A}$ is a set and \contour[2]{black}{$\mathpzc{A}$} is a polyset.
\end{document}
```

I think that the parameter `2` is near to good and correct. Otherwise you set the option with `1`. See the example below with the parameter `1`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{contour}
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
    \begin{document}
    $\mathpzc{A}$ (normal) \contour[1]{black}{$\mathpzc{A}$} (bold)
    \end{document}
```

[image]

You can see with a *zoom in* that you can see the double background, but in the distance it's not obvious.

2. or using an horrible :-) fake bold symbol with `amsbsy` package:

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\begin{document}
$\mathpzc{A}$ is a set and $\pmb{\mathpzc{A}}$ is a polyset.
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**:

3. It is possibile to obtain another best result using [`xfakebold`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xfakebold/doc/xfakebold-doc.pdf) package of Herbert Voß version 0.08 2020-06-24.

---

Comment: Thank you! The fake bold symbol is the best :-).

Comment: @user205875 You're welcome but for my humble opinion the best answer is that of egreg.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is [an XY problem.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean/2450)  What you really want is not “Bold pzc for mathmode,” but a bold mathematical script alphabet.  There are several packages that provide them, but the best are the `\symbfcal` and `\symbfscr` alphabets of [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#29), and the `\mathbcal` and `\mathbscr` alphabets of [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf).  Both provide a comprehensive selection, font samples, scaling and a standard interface for multiple fonts.

As the `mathalpha` documentation warns, Zapf Chancery “is not really suited for use as a math alphabet due to the disparate heights and depths and the long tails on some glyphs.  Use with care.”

Here is a MWE for either modern or classic TeX.  It uses clones of the pxmath/txmath `\mathcal` alphabet.  You might prefer a different set of fonts, but both packages give you many selections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
  \setmathfont{Asana Math}[range={scr,bfscr}, Alternate, Scale=MatchUppercase]
\else
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[scr=pxtx]{mathalpha}
  \newcommand\mathbfscr[1]{\mathbscr{#1}}
\fi

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\(\mathscr A\) is a set and \(\mathbfscr A\) is a polyset.
\end{document}
```

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, this compiles to:

[image: Asana Math sample]

In PDFLaTeX, it compiles to:

[image: pxtx sample]

For what it’s worth, Hermann Zapf did design a calligraphic font specifically for use as a math alphabet: Euler Calligraphic, first used in DEK’s book *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*.  You can get it as the `cal=euler` or `scr=euler` option to `mathalpha`, or as the OpenType math font [Neo Euler.](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)

You could, however, apply egreg’s solution with `FakeBold=` to use the standard `\mathcal` or `\mathscr` alphabets with a clone of Zapf Chancery.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}[range=scr,Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}[range=bfscr,Scale=MatchUppercase,FakeBold=1.2]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\(\mathscr A\) is a set and \(\mathbfscr A\) is a polyset.
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Chorus sample]